# Выплаты на PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-api

Подскажите как реализовать проведение выплат на PayPal.

Я реализовал возможность пополнения личного кабинета юзера.
Реализовал просто, с помощью кнопки PayPal, с проверкой платежа по IPN.

Теперь хочу реализовать возможность выплаты с PayPal аккаунта администратора на аккаунт юзера.

Ну в идеале что бы было в таком духе:

```
$PayPal = new PayPal('admin_paypal_email@gmail.com', 'passs');

$PayPal->payOut('user_paypal_email@gmail.com', 100, 'USD');

if($PayPal->isSuccessPayout()){
    // ok
}
```

А еще лучше пачкой

```
$PayPal->payOut([
    [
    'user_paypal_email' => 'user1_paypal_email@gmail.com'
    'amount' => 100,
    'currency' => 'USD'
    ],[
    'user_paypal_email' => 'user2_paypal_email@gmail.com'
    'amount' => 50,
    'currency' => 'USD'
    ],[
    'user_paypal_email' => 'user3_paypal_email@gmail.com'
    'amount' => 150,
    'currency' => 'USD'
    ],[
    'user_paypal_email' => 'user4_paypal_email@gmail.com'
    'amount' => 70,
    'currency' => 'USD'
    ],
]);
```

Полистал PayPal-PHP-SDK, ничего не понял. Может кто то уже реализовывал, покажите рабочие примеры кода.

Comment: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/

Comment: В целях безопасности не надо делать выплаты такими автоматическими, лучше это делать вручную. А то не дай бог хакнут, и все деньги выведут